# AWS Amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react Authenticator function prop types for typescript issues

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, react-typescript

Spent quite sometime trying to use the relevant types in my aws amplify app which uses the amplify auth.

From the @aws-amplify/ui-react module been struggling to type the props correctly.

documented use case:

```
<Authenticator>
  {({ signOut, user }) => (
      <main>
          <h1>Hello {user?.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
      </main>
  )}
</Authenticator>
```

I would like to type the signOut and user props respectively. The IDE suggests that the props should be typed like so:

signOut is `((data?: (AuthEventData | undefined)) => void) | undefined`

user is `CognitoUserAmplify`

Therefore importing these from the aws-amplify modules throws the following errors:

**Module '"aws-amplify"' has no exported member 'AuthEventData**

**Module '"aws-amplify"' has no exported member 'CognitoUserAmplify'**

What is the recommendation approach if one seeks to add types? All documented demos are in javaScript and no reference to typescript types or typings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the recommended approach is, but I solved it by:

```
import { AuthEventData, CognitoUserAmplify } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react/node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui';

type AppProps = {
    signOut: ((data?: (AuthEventData | undefined)) => void) | undefined;
    user: CognitoUserAmplify | undefined;
};

const App = ({ signOut, user }: AppProps) => {
...
}
```

Comment: Depending upon `@aws-amplify/ui` explicitly, in addition to `@aws-amplify/ui-react`, and using `import { AuthEventData, CognitoUserAmplify } from '@aws-amplify/ui';` is cleaner/safer.  (For people catching up `CognitoUserAmplify` has been deprecated for `AmplifyUser`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that has worked well for me with NextJS (note the 'use client' at the top.

It might help to extend WithAuthenticatorProps locally to add things like Nickname (or what ever additional attributes you want to handle on the Cognito side).

```
'use client'
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify'

import { withAuthenticator, WithAuthenticatorProps } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css'

import awsExports from 'change-me-to-the-path-to-your/aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(awsExports)

const App: React.FC<WithAuthenticatorProps> = (props) => {
  const { user, signOut } = props

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello {user?.attributes?.nickname}</h1>
      <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button><br />
    </>
  )
}

export default withAuthenticator(App)
```